# Create a collection from inside a collection

Tags: json, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection, which when fetched gets a json and puts into collection: 
The JSON format is:

```
[ 
  {
    name: 'Hello',
    age: '22',
    bio: [{
      interest: 'soccer',
      music: 'r&B'
    }]
  }
]
```

I want to make another collection from bio (without fetching again).
The reason is I want to access both name, age and bio and a parse function can have only one return?

```
var user = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/user',

  parse: function (response) {
    //I want both of this?
    //return response;
    return response.bio;
  }
});
```

I am passing this collection on success function of fetch into two different views.

```
//Controller File....
.............

mycollection.fetch({
  success: function() {

    //Details View wants response
    PrimaryLayout.main.show(new detailsView{collection: mycoll});      

   //Bio View wants response.bio
    PrimaryLayout.body.show(new bioView{collection: mycoll}); 
  }
})
```

What would be the best way to tackle this? Can I clone a collection and just have bio in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generally solved this by instantiating the sub-collection in `parse`:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(json) {
        // instantiate the collection
        json.bio = new Backbone.Collection(json.bio);
        // now person.get('bio') will return a Collection object
        return json;
    }
});

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: User,
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for : [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/). Have a look at the tutorials and examples there.